# Recursively search for a directory in Java

Tags: java, search, directory, find

What is the best way to find a directory with a specific name in Java? The directory that I am looking for can be located either in the current directory or one of its subdirectories.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)  Or rather, what are your theories based on testing the best 2 (shrugs) approaches you could think of?  Or does this question actually mean "Can u giv me teh codez?"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution will include the use of `File.listFiles(String)`

[`java.io.File` API reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29)

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I'm constrained 1.6, but I forget that others are not.

Comment: *"I'm constrained 1.6"* As am I (except when I dip back into 1.5 dev. or beyond).  Lucky those docs. have `@since` tags & the compiler has cross-compilation options as the 'acid test' of version compatibility.  I would link to the latest Java Docs even if people mentioned they were developing for Java 1.3. ;)

Answer (score 10):

In Java 8 via the [streams API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html):

```
Optional<Path> hit = Files.walk(myPath)
   .filter(file -> file.getFileName().equals(myName))
   .findAny();
```

The #walk is lazy, so any [short-circuiting terminal operation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps) will optimize the IO required.

Comment: That compares `java.nio.Path` from `Path.getFileName` with `String`. I suggest `file.getFileName().toFile.getName()` knowing that this seems complicated, maybe expensive.

Answer (score 4):

To walk the file tree, [FileVisitor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileVisitor.html) interface can be used.
Please see the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html). Please see [Find sample codes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/examples/Find.java) also.

Comment: This is a better solution than @MadcoreTom's #listFiles as it lets you terminate the walk once the file is found.

Answer (score 3):

As you mentioned recursion should cater to this requirement

```
import java.io.File;

public class CheckFile {

    private static boolean foundFolder = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File dir = new File("currentdirectory");
        findDirectory(dir);
    }

    private static void findDirectory(File parentDirectory) {
        if(foundFolder) {
            return;
        }
        File[] files = parentDirectory.listFiles();
        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isFile()) {
                continue;
            }
            if (file.getName().equals("folderNameToFind")) {
                foundFolder = true;
                break;
            }
            if(file.isDirectory()) {
               findDirectory(file);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Am I correct that this method is not reusable (moving it to some utility class will not work)  i.e. It can detect folder only once and once detected 'foundFolder' will remain to be true?

Answer (score 0):

Divide and conquer?  A naive approach: For every directory, you may start a task, it does the following:

1. list every directory
2. if the list contains a matching directory, prints and exit the application
3. start a task for every directory.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
public static final File findIt(File rootDir, String fileName) {
    File[] files = rootDir.listFiles();
    List<File> directories = new ArrayList<File>(files.length);
    for (File file : files) {
        if (file.getName().equals(fileName)) {
            return file;
        } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
            directories.add(file);
        }
    }

    for (File directory : directories) {
        File file = findIt(directory);
        if (file != null) {
            return file;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, you should use the concept of Recursively search the file until it found: Here is the Code:

```
String name; //to hold the search file name

public String listFolder(File dir) {
    int flag;
    File[] subDirs = dir.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File pathname) {
            return pathname.isDirectory();
        }
    });
    System.out.println("File of Directory: " + dir.getAbsolutePath());
    flag = Listfile(dir);
    if (flag == 0) {
        System.out.println("File Found in THe Directory: " + dir.getAbsolutePath());
        Speak("File Found in THe Directory: !!" + dir.getAbsolutePath());
        return dir.getAbsolutePath();
    }
    for (File folder : subDirs) {
        listFolder(folder);
    }
    return null;
}

private int Listfile(File dir) {
    boolean ch = false;
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    for (File file : files) {
        Listfile(file);
        if (file.getName().indexOf(name.toLowerCase()) != -1) {//check all in lower case
            System.out.println(name + "Found Sucessfully!!");
            ch = true;

        }
    }
    if (ch) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```